# Solve set of poorly conditioned linear equations in block matrix form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I would like to solve the following set of linear equations where A, B, C and D are each 4x4 matrices. K is then an 8x8 matrix

The values in A and D have magnitudes of $\approx 10^{17}$, B has magnitudes of $\approx 10^{3}$ and C magnitudes of $\approx 10^{32}$.

I am having difficulty in calculating $K_3$ where I am subtracting 2 very large numbers and expecting something similar in magnitude to $K_2$ as a result.

\begin{equation}
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
-B&0\\
-D&-I\\
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
K_1&K_2\\
K_3&K_4\\
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
-A&I\\
-C&0\\
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
-BK_1 = -A \quad \quad K_1 = B^{-1}A
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
-BK_2 = I \quad \quad K_2 = -B^{-1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
-D K_1 -I K_3 = -C \quad \quad K_3 = C - D B^{-1}A
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
-D K_2 -I K_4 = 0 \quad \quad K_4 = D B^{-1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
K = 
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
B^{-1}A& - B^{-1}\\
C-DB^{-1}A&DB^{-1}\\
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}

I don't know if it helps but I can factor K out in the following form:

\begin{equation}
K = 
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
-I & 0\\
D &  C\\
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
B^{-1} & 0\\
0 & I\\
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
-A & I\\
I & 0 \\
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
B^{-1}A& - B^{-1}\\
C-DB^{-1}A&DB^{-1}\\
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}

Given the information above is there a nicer way to calculate $K_3$ that would produce more accurate results?

Some specific matrices I am working with are:

\begin{equation}
A = 
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
-9.43455e+17 &-1.12771e+18 &-1.41432e+17 & 8.21904e+18\\
 1.52418e+18 & 1.62684e+18 & 1.96647e+17 &-1.62275e+19\\
-3.16525e+18 &-7.81854e+18 &-1.13337e+18 &-3.34572e+19\\
 1.53908e+17 & 2.89234e+17 & 4.02606e+16 & 2.51396e+17\\
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
B = 
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
-4378.11& -7221.58&  11613.3&   633.99\\
 7221.58&  11144.1& -35042.1& -1460.19\\
-11613.3& -35042.1&  -297926& -6894.17\\
  633.99&  1460.19&  6894.17&  131.919\\
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
C = 
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
-2.01973e+32& -2.33282e+32& -2.89492e+31&  1.88254e+33\\
 2.33282e+32&  2.19587e+32&  2.52959e+31& -2.92849e+33\\
 2.89492e+31&  2.52959e+31&  2.82007e+30& -3.92963e+32\\
 1.88254e+33&  2.92849e+33&  3.92963e+32& -6.14072e+33\\
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
D = 
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
-9.43455e+17& -1.52418e+18&  3.16525e+18&  1.53908e+17\\
 1.12771e+18&  1.62684e+18& -7.81854e+18& -2.89234e+17\\
 1.41432e+17&  1.96647e+17& -1.13337e+18& -4.02606e+16\\
 8.21904e+18&  1.62275e+19&  3.34572e+19&  2.51396e+17\\
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

@ user2235373 , each matrix is known with $6$ significant digits. Unfortunately, $cond(B)\approx 6.10^8$, that implies that $B^{-1}$ is known with $0$ significant digits !

Conclusion: $K$ is absolutely unknown.